# Why are these three lines concurrent?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Consider a triangle $ABC$ with incentre $I$ and let $AI \cap BC=D$.
Let the incentres of $\triangle ACD$ and $\triangle ABD$ be $E$ and $F$ respectively.

Prove that $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ are concurrent.

This is part of a larger problem I am trying to solve and while working on it I noticed that this seemed true both by my diagram and on a (sort of) intuitive level.

Indeed once I placed this in Geogebra I saw this

[image]

Comment: I think it is related to the fact that the angles $\angle BAF$, $\angle FAD$,  $\angle DAE$ and $\angle EAC$ are all equal, but I have not found a proof yet

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. Using that I found the isogonal conjugate of E and F (which gave me the reflection of BE about BF) but that didn't seem to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Note that $E$ and $I$ both lie on the bisector of $\angle C$, so $C$, $E$ and $I$ are collinear. Similarly $B$, $F$ and $I$ are collinear.

Since $F$ lies on the angle bisector of angle $\angle BAI$, we have $\frac{|BF|}{|FI|} = \frac{|AB|}{|AI|}$ by the angle bisector theorem. In the same way, we have $\frac{|IE|}{|EC|} = \frac{|AI|}{|AC|}$. By the angle bisector theorem in $\triangle ABC$ we have $\frac{|CD|}{|DB|} = \frac{|AC|}{|AB|}$. This entails that
$$
\frac{|BF|}{|FI|} \frac{|IE|}{|EC|} \frac{|CD|}{|DB|} = \frac{|AB|}{|AI|} \frac{|AI|}{|AC|} \frac{|AC|}{|AB|} = 1.
$$
Since $D$, $E$ and $F$ lie on the interior of the sides of triangle $\triangle BIC$, [Ceva's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) now implies that $BE$, $CF$ and $DI$ are concurrent.